# Orthogonality in Wasserstein tangent space for discrete measures with equal mass

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Let say I have $N$ discrete probability measures $(\mu_1,...,\mu_N)$ where each of them has $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of equal mass.

Let $P(\mathcal{X})$ be the space of these probability measures on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{X}$ (which is $\mathbb{R}^2$ in our case if I'm not mistaken).

We can define the Wasserstein barycenter:

$\overline{\mu} = argmin_{\nu \in P(\mathcal{X})} \sum_i^N \alpha_i W_2^2(\mu_i, \nu)$.

Under the 2-Wasserstein metric $W_2$ and with $\alpha_i = \frac{1}{N},_{i=1..N}$ (in our case).

I'm interested to grap the intuition with the tangent space at $\overline{\mu}$. Especially in the notion of orthogonality in this tangent space.

Let say I have a vector (or velocity) field $v_1 \in L^2(\overline{\mu}, \mathcal{X})$ (the tangent space at $\overline{\mu}$), containing $n$ vectors, that move all the $n$ masses of $\overline{\mu}$ in a direction $v_1^i,_{i=1..n}$ respectively.

What would it mean to have a velocity field $v_2 \in L^2(\overline{\mu}, \mathcal{X})$ orthogonal to $v_1$ in the $L^2(\overline{\mu}, \mathcal{X})$ sense? It is just that we need to have $v_2^i \perp v_1^i,_{i=1..n}$ in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ sense?

I'm interested in any reference that could help (especially because I could need to cite something) and any explications.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it completely clear that the barycenter $\bar\mu$ is also atomic with exactly the same number $n$ of masses as the  $\mu_i$'s?

Comment: If you know somehow that $\bar\mu=\sum\bar\mu^j\delta_{x_j}$ then the velocity-fields $v_1(x),v_2(x)$ are canonicallly given by discrete vector fields $v^j_1,v^j_2\in \mathbb R^2$ over each point $x_j$ for $j=1\dots N$. And in this case the orthogonality in $L^2(\bar\mu)$ simply means that $\int <v^1(x),v^2(x)>d\bar\mu(x)=\sum_j \bar \mu^j <v^1_j,v^2_j>=0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. Indeed in my case the barycenter will have $$ points with equal mass as the $_$. Thanks for the explanation, however, when you said "over each point $_$ for$ =1...$", would you mean "$=1...$"? Meaning that the points $_$ that you are talking about are the $$ points in the barycenter? Finally, how can we justify this result? Or, is it too much straightforward to be justified? Or, the final formula that you give is the justification according some definitions?

Comment: yes, I meant $j=1\dots n$, but comments cannot be edited after 5 mins. The $x_j$ are indeed the points in the barycenter, as indicated. Finally, there is nothing to justify: the Wasserstein scalar product is by definition $\int <v^1(x),v^2(x)>d\bar\mu(x)$, and when $\bar\mu$ is atomic the integral is just the sum as in my previous comment. I doubt that anyone would ask for a reference here, and I can only advise that you think for a few minutes about what the space $L^2(\delta)$ is over a Dirac-Delta reference measure.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your explanation and your advice. Indeed, as you may have seen this is not my main domain of work but I needed to be sure about this.